# performance tuning ask for advice

Tags: proxy, debugging, performance

I found when I turn off (un-select) automatically detect proxies setting in Internet 
Options, my application (which involves a lot of Http based network communication) 
performance will boost a lot. Now I want to prove that performance issue is actually caused by automatically proxy detection.

Any ideas from debugger or from other points to prove?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 3):

You could use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to analyze your theory.

Comment: Or Microsoft Network Monitor, if the word "Microsoft" will add an aura of correctness.

Comment: Hi Karsten, I used wireshark before, but how to prove traffic is exactly spend on waiting to automatically detect proxy? I want to know what kinds of traffic in wireshark is traffic to automatically detect proxy?

Comment: Hi John, if I use Microsoft Network Minitor, from where could I know some specific traffic is used to do automatic proxy detection?

Comment: John and Karsten, I have tried but no traffic captured seems to be traffic used to automatically detect proxy. Any ideas?

Comment: Wireshark captures *all* network activity on the machine.  If it's happening, then you *will* see it.  If you think there are issues in the browser, check out performance on Firefox by using Firebug and YSlow. http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/ http://getfirebug.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Microsoft Visual Round Trip Analyzer (VRTA)](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=119f3477-dced-41e3-a0e7-d8b5cae893a3&displaylang=en). Run one series of tests with automatic proxy detection on, then the same series with it off. It's important to do multiple tests and take the average across the tests, in order to account for usual network randomness.

Comment: Very cool tool, Patrick! I have tried this tool, but I am confused about how to identify from this tool to see how much traffic or latency used to automatically detect proxy? I just see very general information from this tool, like overall bandwidth or something.

Comment: @George2; VRTA just gives a nicer interface to NetMon. I see from your comment that you've tried NetMon and it didn't seem to help, so I don't think VRTA will be of much help then either. Sorry :(